# WPF library to display audio waveform

Tags: wpf, audio, waveform

Does anyone know of a nice library to give me audio wavform functionallity, specifically:

- Load audio file
- Display waveform
- Play file or selection
- etc

I have used Adobe Audition in the past, so something like the way they display their waveforms would be great.

See the screen capture below.

[image: Screen capture from Adobe Audition 3.0]

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look on WPF Sound Visualization Library:  http://wpfsvl.codeplex.com/

Edit: Project Moved To https://github.com/jacobjohnston/wpfsvl